# my component is not re-rendering on state change react native

Tags: react-native

this is my declaration of state :

```
 state = {
    shouldShow1: Boolean = false,
    shouldShow2: Boolean = false,
    shouldShow3: Boolean = false,
    shouldShow4: Boolean = false,
    shouldShow5: Boolean = false,
    shouldShow6: Boolean = false,
    shouldShow7: Boolean = false,
    shouldShow8: Boolean = false,
    shouldShow9: Boolean = false,
  };
```

then i change the value of one state each time the user click on button

```
  if (this.state.shouldShow1 == false) {
          this.state.shouldShow1 = await true;
          this.state.shouldShow2 = false;
          this.state.shouldShow3 = false;
          this.state.shouldShow4 = false;
          this.state.shouldShow5 = false;
          this.state.shouldShow6 = false;
          this.state.shouldShow7 = false;
          this.state.shouldShow8 = false;
          this.state.shouldShow9 = false;
.............
```

and i have a code like this in the render

```
return(
{this.state.shouldShow1 == true ? Show View A : Show View B  }

{this.state.shouldShow2 == true ? Show View A : Show View B }
)
```

Comment: the problem is that i can see the state changing but the views doesn't change please i need help with this i'm still learning and i'm stuck with it

Comment: You should use this.setState({ shouldShow1: true, shouldShow2: true, .... })

Comment: thank you, that was the problem and i fixed it, now it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bernhard Josephus answered resolved my problem the solution is :

i should have used  this.setState({ shouldShow1: true, shouldShow2: true, .... })
instead of just affecting values.